# Learning .prototype

Tags: javascript

***Edit: for those people seeing this post in the future, [this site](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/) was undoubtedly critical for me to digest Javascript. If you're coming from a traditional OOP background, I HIGHLY recommend it. The UML-esq diagrams were amazing.***

I still can't get my head around what the .prototype property in Javascript is. Is it simply a reference to another object? Or is it a reference to a pointer to another object? I come from C/C++/x86 and just can't see how it works. Let's look at some examples of how I currently see things; it'd help to point out my errors to see how things work. I don't even know if some of these are valid syntax. `Object` and `Function` are the global object/function objects respectively.

```
1                                        // Global.prototype = ??
2                                        // Function.prototype = ??
3 
4   var obj1 = {};                       // obj1.prototype = Object 
5   obj2 = {};                           // obj2.prototype = Object
6
7   var func1 = function() {};           // func1.prototype = Function
8   func2 = function() {};               // func2.prototype = Function
9   function func3() {}                  // func3.prototype = Function  
10
```

I'm so confused.

```
11  var Foo = function() { this.prop1 = 0; }
12  var foo = new Foo();                 // should it be 'new Foo' or 'new Foo()'?
13  // Foo.prototype = Function
14  // foo.prototype = Foo
15  var Goo = function() { this.prop2 = 0; }
16  var goo = new Goo();
17  // goo.prototype = Goo
18  goo.prototype = new Foo();
19  // goo.prop1 now exists ?
```

I also don't understand swapping prototypes around.

```
20  function A () {
21     this.prop1 = 1;
22  }
23  function B () {
24     this.prop2 = 2;
25  }
26  function C () {
27     this.prop3 = 3;
28  }
29  C.prototype = new B();
30  var c = new C();
31  // c.prop1 = 1
32  // c.prop2 = 2
33  // c.prop3 = undefined
34  C.prototype = new A();
35  // c.prop2 = 2???
36  // c.prop3 = 3
```

I can't get a grasp on the concept. I don't quite understand. I don't get how cloned objects get their own local copies of data, but changes to the original object (the prototype) somehow cascade down to the clones. I've been fiddling around with FigureBug trying things out, but mentally I can't come up with an idea that is consistent with every example ive seen

C++ may be a huge monstrosity, but at least I know **exactly** what's going. Here... I'm using my best guess.. 
Just a new paradigm I suppose. Anyways, thanks if you can help out... I'm turned upside-down on this .prototype.

Comment: Check my answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047025/trying-to-understand-javascript-inheritence/17049716#17049716

Comment: if you ask for obj.x and obj doesn't have it's own x property, JS will check for the existence of obj.prototype.x, and if present, return it, otherwise returning undefined. think of it as call-forwarding for programming, prototype is an alternate number you can try to reach the data at. Since it's a different phone, you can still call the main line if the alternate is destroyed.

Comment: @dandavis OK I get that scenario. What I don't get it what .prototype references, what it is set to by default, and what happens when I start swapping prototypes aroud

Comment: @gone. ".prototype" refs a different object, a plain old object, nothing magic. by default, the constructor has a different prototype than the instance. by default it's {} for constructor functions and Object.prototype for objects. if you use new, it's like saying inst=Con.call({}}, transering all the "this." bindings in Con to the blank object passed. new also hard-wires the .prototype property of an instance to point to the .prototype property of it's constructor.

Comment: @dandavis Ohhh. So if I invoke a functional object following the `new` keyword, the empty object (returned)'s `.prototype` is set to the `.prototype` of the functional object in which we are invoking?

Comment: Argh, I've written an extensive answer but can't post it now due to closing!

Comment: @Bergi Aghh. It's different then the linked question too (albeit similar titles). If you email it to me I'll read it :)

Comment: @Bergi: yes, instance.prototype essentially refers to Constructor.prototype, if there were such a thing as instance.prototype. ex:  function A(){this.a=1;} A.prototype={b:2}; var a=new A(); Object.getPrototypeOf(a)==A.prototype;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, that's a lot of questions. Let's work through them.

> Is it simply a reference to another object? Or is it a reference to a pointer to another object?

There are no pointers in JavaScript. Yet, a variable or property holding "an object" is actually holding a reference to the object, so other variables can hold references to the same object.

> ```
> Global.prototype = ??
> ```

The global object (`window` if you want), where all global variables are defined, has no prototype (don't care about exceptions in some environments).

> I still can't get my head around what the .prototype property in Javascript is.

The `.prototype` property is a property that all function objects have, pointing to their prototype object (a plain object).

You must not confuse it with the internal *prototype* reference which each object has. That *prototype* points to the object where properties are looked up which an object doesn't have itself.

> ```
> Function.prototype = ??
> ```

This is the object from which all Function objects inherit. It contains things like `call` or `bind`.

> ```
> var obj1 = {};              // obj1.prototype = Object
> var func1 = function() {};  // func1.prototype = Function
> ```

Yes, kinda. I think you've got the concept, but didn't know the terminology. While `func.prototype` is a different thing, the `obj.prototype` property doesn't even exist. However, you meant the internal *prototypes* - we can access them via the `Object.getPrototypeOf` function. And they don't refer to the constructor functions, but their prototype objects. Here's the correction:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1) === Object.prototype
Object.getPrototypeOf(func1) === Function.prototype
```

> should it be 'new Foo' or 'new Foo()'?

That doesn't matter, they're equivalent. You only need the brackets explicitly when you want to pass arguments.

> ```
> var Foo = function() { this.prop1 = 0; }
> var foo = new Foo();
> ```

Again, your assumptions were correct but expressed wrong. Let's work through the details.

Above, I've talked about "prototype objects". What are those? They are plain objects which get implicitly created with every function. In this case, it's `Foo.prototype` - an empty object. So we deal here with three objects: The `Foo` constructor function, its `Foo.prototype` prototype object and the `foo` instance.

What's special about `foo`? It's the first thing which the `new` operator does. When a function is getting invoked as a constructor - with `new` - then its `.prototype` property is accessed and a new object is instantiated with its internal *prototype* set to that prototype object. That's the miraculous thing. After that the function is called on the new instance so that `this` is the new object; and in your case it creates the `.prop1` property on the instance. Then the result is returned (and assigned to `foo`).

How to make use of that magic now? The point is to create properties on the prototype object, which will be inherited then.

```
// modify `Foo.prototype`, the object which `foo` inherits from:
Foo.prototype.prop2 = 1;
console.log(foo.prop2); // 1!
```

> I also don't understand swapping prototypes around.

The problem is that this is quite impossible. Once instantiated, an object's prototype chain is quite static. However, you don't need that often.

> ```
> goo.prototype = new Foo();
> ```

That didn't work because the `.prototype` property is not what you expected.

> ```
> var c = new C();
> C.prototype = new A();
> ```

That does work only a littlebit. Have a look above at what `new` does - it looks up the `.prototype` property of the constructor only once. The internal *prototype* stays locked then - you don't change the `c` instance. However, if you would create a new instance `var d = new C()` now then it would inherit from the `A` instance.

I hope this helps; if you have further questions please comment.

Comment: Sorry I was late about it. But yes. This is it. "The problem is that this is quite impossible": exactly what I needed (along with everything else you mentioned)> Very much appreciated; top notch answer imo

Answer (score 2):

The prototype is used to search properties when the object itself doesn't have it defined, during reads. Writes always happen on the object itself

When you call

```
// An instance of Foo ({prop1:0}) is set as the 
// prototype (to all instances of Goo)
var goo = new Goo();

// 0, from the prototype
console.log(goo.prop1); 

// Read from the object itself (set in Goo's constructor)
console.log(goo.prop2); 

// New instance, same prototype as goo
var goo2 = new Goo();
console.log(goo2.prop1) ; // 0, still from the prototype

// Setting is always at the object level, not the prototype
goo.prop1 = 5;

// goo2 is still reading from the prototype
console.log(goo2.prop1);
```

**N.B.**

Don't instantiate the parent class just to setup inheritance. See why here http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html