# javascript inherance? with Private vars and methods too

Tags: javascript

Hy i need to inherent a class from another.

Parent has private var "_data" and private method "_test" and public method "add"
Now the child have a public method "add", that uses the private method from the parent "_test" and the private var "_data".

How do i do this?

```
var Parent = function(){
    var _data = {};
    var _test = function(){alert('test')};
    this.add = function(){alert('add from parent')}
}

var Child = function(){
    this.add = function(){// here uses the _data and _test from the Parent class
        alert('add from child')
    }
}

// something to inherent Child from Parent
// instance Child and use the add method
```

And i think im miss the prototype concept ([Javascript inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892467/javascript-inheritance))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple inheritance:

```
function createChild(){
    Child.prototype=new Parent()
    return new Child()
}
```

This way you get a fresh initialization of Parent for every Child.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the way you do inheritance in JavaScript is by assigning the `Child` class's prototype property to an instance of the `Parent` object. So you'd define your constructor function for `Child`:

`function Child() {  /* initialization yadda yadda */ }`

and then do this:

`Child.prototype = new Parent();`

which is more or less equivalent to `Class Child extends Parent` in other languages -- Child then has the methods, members, and, via closure, the private members of a Parent object.

There's a couple of tricky points here. One of them is initialization done in the constructor. Calling the Parent constructor in the Child constructor function explicitly ( `function Child() { Parent(); }`) seems to be the most obvious tack, but problematic because of the way `this` is handled and returned from an initialization (inside the function `Parent` what's `this`?). You can work around this by using the `apply` method of `Function` (which every function has access to):

`function Child() { 
    Parent.apply(this,arguments);
    //initialization unique to Child goes here
}`

(See http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply for more on apply)

But the way I usually do it is to break all the initialization for classes into a separate "init" function that sortof replaces the constructor.

`function Parent() { this.init(); }`

Parent.prototype.init = function () { /* initialization yadda yadda */ }

That way, this is simply inherited along with everything else... or I can write a new one that calls the old one if I like:

`Child.prototype.init = function () {
     Parent.prototype.init.apply(this,arguments); 
     /* insert stuff unique to child constructor here */
}`

The other tricky bit is access to `Parent`'s private members. You can't do it, really, except by `Parent`'s methods. They're truly private, not "protected," "subclasses" can't see them except by methods they inherit. There are some ways of writing around that, but that's probably another Q/A, the simplest one is to make sure you design your `Parent` well.

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries which extend JavaScript with OOP-like features. Maybe you find something in [John Resigs Blog Entry](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) on JS inheritance (via base2 and Prototype).